# HAT EEPROM DTB and RTC on I2C0

Tags: i2c, hat, rtc, ds1307, eeprom

I'm having a problem creating a DTB for a HAT auto-configuration.

I have a DS3231 RTC module attached on `I2C0` (`GPIO0` and `GPIO1`). It incorporates an AT24C32 EEPROM at address `0x50`.

To get it working, without getting into the HAT part yet, I've added following lines to `/boot/config.txt`.
I've checked and I need `i2c_vc=on` in order for it to create `/dev/rtc0` and detect the RTC as it should.

```
dtparam=i2c_vc=on
dtoverlay=i2c-rtc,ds3231,i2c0
```

Now I want to create a DTB to be embedded in HAT EEPROM so it would be auto-configured without requiring to edit any file.
For this, I just checked out `eepromutils` and created `eeprom.eep` successfully, also flashing it to the AT24C32 without problems, verified it creates `/proc/device-tree/hat` with the parameters.

I know I can load a DTB blob or name at boot using the EEPROM, so I installed `dtc` and used `arch/arm/boot/dts/overlays` files from `raspberrypi/linux` at default branch.
However, after flashing the new `eeprom.eep` and also putting `hub.dtbo` in `/boot/overlays` and adding `dtoverlay=hub` to `/boot/config.txt` doesn't create `/dev/rtc0` at all, and `i2cdetect` shows up `0x68` as free (not `UU`).

Things I tried to create `hub-overlay.dts` (and `hub.dtbo`):

```bash
# try 1
ovmerge -c i2c-rtc-overlay.dts,ds3231,i2c0
dtc -@ -Hepapr -I dts -O dtb -o hub.dtbo hub-overlay.dts
```

```bash
# try 2
ovmerge -c i2c0-overlay.dts,pins_0_1 i2c-rtc-overlay.dts,ds3231,i2c0
dtc -@ -Hepapr -I dts -O dtb -o hub.dtbo hub-overlay.dts
```

I also tried writing the `hub-overlay.dts` manually like so:

```
/dts-v1/;
/plugin/;

/ {
    compatible = "brcm,bcm2835";
    fragment@0 {
        target = <&i2c0>;
        __overlay__ {
            status = "okay";
            #address-cells = <1>;
            #size-cells = <0>;
            ds3231@68 {
                compatible = "maxim,ds3231";
                reg = <0x68>;
            };
        };
    };
};
```

I'm aware that I need something like `dtparam=i2c_vc=on` but in DTS form, but setting `<&i2c0>` `status` to `"okay"` is far more than completely what I need given that it doesn't create a `/dev/i2c-0` device nor loads any driver for RTC workings.

Any advice on how to get it working? I'm trying to get this done without any file modifications if possible.
Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually meant to use i2c0 for any of your own devices - it's meant to handle just the VideoCore stuff and the HAT EEPROM. Normally, it is made unavailable to the CPU during boot, after the EEPROM has been read, and I've read several warnings that keeping it active may cause problems. It might work better if you put the RTC on i2c1 instead.

However, I'm having trouble getting a HAT working with i2c1, so I'm not sure yet what to recommend. :) I've posted a question today about that one.